# If Blade (the film version) were to procreate with a normal human, would the offspring gain his powers?

Tags: marvel, blade

In the *Blade* movies, vampires can have "pure bloods" with other vampires, or create "newborns" via biting and transferring the vampiric virus to normal humans. Blade was a unique case, as his *mother* was turned into a vamp, and as she was changing her amniotic fluid changed, making him essentially *half* vampire. As a result, he has all their strengths, but none of their weaknesses.

We saw Blade bite a normal human (Nbushe Wright in the first movie) and she didn't seem to change at all. However, would his biological *offspring* with a human also be half vampire? Or would they be something else?

What if he were to sire a child with a full vampire like Nysa (from the second film)? Would that child be more vampire or Daywalker?

Are there any comic book or novelization references that addressed this?

Comment: I don't know that this was ever addressed in the movies (which were concerned with other aspects of Blade's life), so we probably just plain don't know.

Comment: @ZeissIkon hence me asking if it was addressed anywhere else. Blade's unique status apparently was something that was hard to recreate naturally, hence the use of genetic manipulation to make super-vamps in the second film. However, it was never stated that he _couldn't_ have children, and its not unlikely _Some_ of his genetics would show up in them. It would probably be different with a human mother, as opposed to a vampire mother, so I was wondering.

Comment: [Fallon Grey was going to be Blade's daughter to a mortal woman](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Vol_6). She was going to have vampiric powers and the plot reads like a ripoff of "Teen-wolf meets Buffy". In the end the writer left the project after it was delayed and critics started making unpleasant noises about a white (Caucasian) writer writing predominantly black (African American) comic characters.

Comment: @Valorum Well...people will take issue with that kind of thing,but that's like saying a black man can't write fantasy about Vikings or European castles; kind of one-sided. Then again, I recently read that Blade has similar effects under a red sun that normal vampires do under a yellow sun. And considering _Underworld,_ and how it deals with characters of all colors, it would have been an interesting story to read.

Answer (score 2):

In the comic continuity, there was [a plan](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Blade_Vol_6) to have Blade partner with his daughter, Fallon Grey, the offspring of Blade and an unnamed human woman. Fallon is superpowered and was going to have a similar (but non-identical) power set to Blade.

> **Tim Seeley:** *Well basically, it’s Blade’s daughter, but there’s a hitch: Blade doesn’t recall having a daughter or conceiving a daughter so he’s sort of confused on how she can be his kid. **She’s a sixteen year-old girl that has some of his powers that seems connected to his.***
>
> **Newsarama: *We already know who her possible father is, but what are the chances of finding out about her mother?***
>
> **Seeley:** *That’s definitely part of the story and a big part of the mystery the woman he believes to be the mother that he doesn’t remember meeting. Yeah, we’ll have some cool twists about it, but we’re sort of playing with the idea that since Blade is a half-vampire that he’s more evolved, but **she’s something else entirely. So she has more elevated abilities than he does** and so the ability to walk in the daylight is[n't] that impressive to her when it comes to what she can do.*
>
> <sub><sup>[SEELEY Promises New Blood, New Characters & 'No Vampires' in BLADE](https://www.newsarama.com/25203-seeley-reveals-no-vampires-in-blade-series.html)</sup></sub>